# Parsing errors when loading dataset

Tags: r, readr

I was given the code below to customize the variable types and it doesn't know how to interpret "f". any ideas on how to fix this?

```
library(readr)
data2014 <- read_csv("data2014.csv", col_types = cols(
  .default = "f",
  Time = col_skip(),
  Minutes = col_integer(),
  Seconds = col_integer(),
  Away = col_character(),
  Away_Points_Added = col_integer(),
  Score = col_character(),
  Home_Points_Added = col_integer(),
  Home = col_character()
))
```

Error: Unknown shortcut: f

Comment: According to the git blame that shortcut was added 6 months ago by the look of it, https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/cd68d4ab6009109cf94d31c49bdfe04c2f7cf36c/R/col_types.R#L367, probably update your library?

Comment: THAT WORKED! My goodness, haven't had to update a library yet (still sorta new to r) thank you so much!